# any tool to view currently running scripts behind the scenes on a web page?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, scripting, modalpopupextender

I have a asp.net application with silverlight file upload control (http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/).  when i try to hide the control after popup of modalpopupextender, some thing is running behind scenes, which takes all of the resources.  Want to check what script is running behind the scenes.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, you can edit it. If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox, or Chrome's built in developer tools